# Magento 2 - products import error

Tags: magento2, import, importexport

I am trying to import translated product names, descriptions via CSV file, but the bar at import page keeps loading and exceptions is triggered via AJAX call.

I tried:

- changing file encoding,
- different values,
- modifying exported csv file and reimporting

but somehow I always got the same error.

**CSV code - Exception report**

This is a sample CSV which I am trying to import

```
sku,store_view_code,product_websites,attribute_set_code,product_type,name,short_description,description
1001,en,,Default,simple,"Battery Canon NB-1LH - Patona","<p>Battery Canon NB-1LH - Patona</p>","<p>Battery Canon NB-1LH - Patona</p>"
```

and this is the report of an exception

```
a:4:{i:0;s:36:"Please enter a correct entity model.";i:1;s:6936:"#0 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Import.php(689): Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import->_getEntityAdapter()
#1 /home/randuser/public_html/var/generation/Magento/ImportExport/Model/Import/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import->isReportEntityType('catalog_product')
#2 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Import.php(718): Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Interceptor->isReportEntityType('catalog_product')
#3 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Import.php(534): Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import->createHistoryReport('importexport/ca...', 'catalog_product', 'csv', Array)
#4 /home/randuser/public_html/var/generation/Magento/ImportExport/Model/Import/Interceptor.php(141): Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import->uploadSource()
#5 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/module-import-export/Controller/Adminhtml/Import/Validate.php(39): Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Interceptor->uploadSource()
#6 /home/randuser/public_html/var/generation/Magento/ImportExport/Controller/Adminhtml/Import/Validate/Interceptor.php(25): Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Validate->execute()
#7 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Validate\Interceptor->execute()
#8 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Validate\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#12 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\ImportE...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Validate\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#13 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Validate\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\ImportE...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Validate\Interceptor), Array, 'designLoader')
#17 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/Design.php(39): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Validate\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#20 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\ImportE...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Validate\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#21 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Validate\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 [internal function]: Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Validate\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(140): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#24 /home/randuser/public_html/var/generation/Magento/ImportExport/Controller/Adminhtml/Import/Validate/Interceptor.php(40): Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Validate\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#25 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\Validate\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#28 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#29 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#30 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(140): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#33 /home/randuser/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#34 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /home/randuser/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#36 /home/randuser/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#37 {main}";s:3:"url";s:154:"/klikadmin/admin/import/validate/key/5964a641c3aaf36379fd211ed5e608771ab26ff08cec0311c769adbdc13a4d1e/?form_key=K9jCxmUPY51wky0z&form_key=K9jCxmUPY51wky0z";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Answer (score -1):

If maybe someone else gets to the same problem.

**This bug was fixed in Magento 2.0.3.**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/59534)

Comment: You expect me to paste code from Magento and analyze the bug?

The guy had a problem which was the same as mine and it was resolved in Magento 2.0.3.  There is not much to discuss here....